# Cannot login with a password

Tags: 16.04, login, password, passwd

I am running Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS on an iMac.  I am the administrator of six users, and none of them can login with a password.  Only the administrators with `sudo` privs can use a password.  When you try to change the password through Settings > Users and Groups, it successfully changes the password, but when you log out and try to log in again, it doesn't ask for a password and just logs in when you click the user name.  This is also the case when I use the `passwd` command through the terminal.

```
user@ubuntu-imac:~$ passwd
Changing password for user.
(current) UNIX password: 
Enter new UNIX password: 
Retype new UNIX password: 
passwd: password updated successfully
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: Are the users in the `nopasswdlogin` group (`getent group nopasswdlogin`)?

Comment: @steeldriver I just checked.  Everybody is in that group.  Can you please post the solution as an answer?

Comment: Are your users in the group nopasswdlogin?

Comment: @steeldriver you beat me by 45 seconds :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `lightdm` GUI display manager allows users to login without providing their UNIX account password if they are members of the `nopasswdlogin` group.

You can check which users are members of the group using `getent` e.g.

```
getent group nopasswdlogin
```

You can remove users from the group a number of ways - IMHO the `gpasswd` utility is the most straightforward e.g.

```
sudo gpasswd --delete carol nopasswdlogin
```

Alternatively, set the group membership to s specific list of allowed users using the `-M` (`--members`) switch:

```
sudo gpasswd --members alice,bob nopasswdlogin
```

You can remove *all* users from the group (thereby requiring all users to supply their UNIX passwords for GUI login) by setting the group membership to an empty list i.e.

```
sudo gpasswd -M '' nopasswdlogin
```

See `man gpasswd`.

Comment: Thank you!  That worked perfectly.  Just as a side note, I found out that you can also use the `deluser` command to remove a user from a group.